# Setup xdebug - doesn't appear on phpinfo();

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

MAC OS X 10.7.5
MAMP PRO 2.0.5

If I do:

```
php --ini
```

I get:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf
Loaded Configuration File:         /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)
Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)
```

On:

```
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/php.ini
```

I have:

```
[xdebug] 
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9001
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug.log"
```

I then see phpinfo(), information I got NO xdebug information at all.

xdebug.so IS on this path.

I do have restart the apache server (using MAMP);

Can anyone drop me a clue here ?

UPDATE:

Just notice that on phpinfo I have:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   
/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf

Loaded Configuration File   
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

I don't understand which one is he actually looking at.
Anyway, changed on both. No luck.

Comment: Just shooting in the dark here - did you try restart apache?

Comment: Yes. Several times. :s Really not understanding this.

Comment: At least a way to discover where should I look at, or what else can I check, would help... :)

Comment: In term terminal try to access/open /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so to ensure your path is valid. Also, make certain you disable Zend Optimizer as it conflicts with XDebug. Assuming a fresh MAMP install, walk/rewalk through these instructions: https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/php/configure-php-environment-mac-os.html#installEnableXdebug Sometimes completely removing and restarting a new install just magically works.

Comment: @BrianDHall thanks a lot. I can access the file. I don't have any `zend_optimizer` declaration on php.ini as described on netbeans documentation. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, the file that should be edited according to Xdebug oficial information is:

```
/Library/Application Support/appsolute/MAMP PRO/conf/php.ini
```

And apparently as well, in order to change that file you should use MAMP PRO options, otherwise, the file will always revert to the prior state.

So, to solve those issue I had to:

```
MAMP PRO > File > Edit Template > PHP > PHP 5.3.6 php.ini
```

And then remove the comment (;) on:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/xdebug.so"
```

I can now see xdebug on phpinfo();